# Manipulate excel file and plot

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a number of `.csv` files that have the following format:

[image]

I want to do the following:

1. ignore the last two rows
2. sort all the remaining rows w.r.t the 2nd column
3. pick all the rows whose values are less than the value in the 2nd last line (e.g. `388.03912` in the image above),
4. and generate the box plot for the first column such as this:

[image]

Having said that, this is what I have done:

```
$dataDirectory = "C:\\Users\\bchilukuri3\\Documents\\myDir\\";
readFiles@$dataDirectory

readFiles[directory_] := Module[{files}, files = FileNames["*.csv", directory]; 
                                         {FileNameTake[#, -1], process@#} & /@ files]

process[files_] := Module[{d1, d2, th},
                   d1 = Import[files]; 
                   d2 = Sort[d1[[;; -3]], 2];(* does not work because of parentheses*)
                   th = Flatten@d1[[-2]];(* threshold value*)

                   d3 = picksorted[d2, th];(*pick useful values based on the `th`*)
                   BoxWhiskerChart[d3[[1]]]
];

picksorted[d2_, th_] :=(*not sure how to pick appropriate rows*)
```

Please help!!

sample data is shared [here](http://ge.tt/3AcjwsE2/v/0?c)!!

Comment: I will appreciate if people who down votes/voted this question gives justification with some comments/links!!

Comment: One reason why one might want to downvote this question is because it has a "give me the code" character. You haven't put enough effort into isolating your problem. It could very well be that if you had put down some effort to isolate the problem then you would have solved it by yourself.

Comment: @Pickett I do not agree that my question has "give me code" character. I provided the framework for the program and only wanted  help with certain functions.  I learnt quite a few things from your code; e.g. `ToExpression` and `First@*Last`were not obvious to a amateur like me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = ToExpression@Import["~/Downloads/TI_1900_0.07_781.csv"];

process[raw_] := Module[{data, threshold},
  data = raw[[;; -3]];
  data = SortBy[data, First@*Last];

  threshold = raw[[-2, 1]];
  data = Select[data, #[[2, 1]] > threshold &];
  BoxWhiskerChart[
   data[[1 ;; 15, 1]]
   ]
  ]

process[data]
```

Note two things

1. I've changed `<` into `>` in `Select` because otherwise there were no matches.
2. I'm only plotting the first fifteen values in the box chart, plotting 27399 boxes makes no sense and is very slow.

Comment: worked fine..Thanks